# How to fix error when sending mail with django in docker container? (Cannot assign requested address)

Tags: python, django, docker, smtp

I'm getting an error when sending a letter both in Celery, as in the shell itself. Without the docker itself, there is no such error on the local computer, but there is on the server.

Error:

```
    send_mail('test', 'test msg', 'volkodav2312@bk.ru', ['volkodav2312@inbox.ru'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 87, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 80, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 845, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I looked through the other answers and didn't find anything helpful. I have a password configured, this error occurs in the docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address` this means the provide `ip/port` is already taken.Change your `ip/port` and try again

find `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: ['192.107.1.2:8000:8000'] # <-- change IP and port here
```

Try this

Comment: Do you mean that I need to add a port to docker-compose in django? I use google, does that mean I need to do this?  django:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
      - '587:587'
    container_name: django

Comment: you have to do it in docker

Comment: Do you have a link to an article on how to do it? I'll be very thankful

Comment: Unfortunately the error has not been fixed. :c

Comment: Here is a tutorial on setting up docker with django.https://justdjango.com/blog/django-docker-tutorial#:~:text=Dockerizing%20Django%201%20Getting%20Started%20Firstly%2C%20install%20Docker.,not%20execute%20properly.%20...%205%20Final%20Changes%20 .please follow it from top to bottom

Comment: Dear friend, it looks like I have ports closed on my server. I created a ticket, it turns out that indeed all smtp ports are closed. Thank you for your help!